# Copying data from one collection to another in MongoDB with Mongoose results in VersionError

Tags: javascript, mongodb, post, mern

Mongoose can't find matching document with id when copying data from one collection to another.

I have a site where a user searches for a class in a Mongo DB collection called classes. Once it finds the class (which works), it should add a copy of that class to a Collection called classes_taken. However, I run into this error:

```
VersionError: No matching document found for id "64779936f186a42f6b09658b" version 0 modifiedPaths "_id, has_final, description, offered_fall, offered_spring, meets_with_subjects, instructors, joint_subjects, total_units, related_subjects, hass_attribute, pdf_option, is_half_class, level, url, subject_id, title, lab_units, design_units, public, offered_summer, lecture_units, preparation_units, is_variable_units, offered_IAP"
    at generateVersionError (/Users/nayeemurrahman/Documents/Projects/extinguisher/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:461:10)
    at model.save (/Users/nayeemurrahman/Documents/Projects/extinguisher/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:518:28)
    at /Users/nayeemurrahman/Documents/Projects/extinguisher/server/index.js:44:20
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  version: 0,
  modifiedPaths: [
    '_id',               'has_final',
    'description',       'offered_fall',
    'offered_spring',    'meets_with_subjects',
    'instructors',       'joint_subjects',
    'total_units',       'related_subjects',
    'hass_attribute',    'pdf_option',
    'is_half_class',     'level',
    'url',               'subject_id',
    'title',             'lab_units',
    'design_units',      'public',
    'offered_summer',    'lecture_units',
    'preparation_units', 'is_variable_units',
    'offered_IAP'
  ]
```

This is my code for this process:

```
 // POST request to add a class taken
  app.post("/addClass", async (req, res) => {
  // let's say a string was sent in the request body
  // take that string and find the class in the database
  // add that class to the database of classes taken

  const subject_id = req.body.subject_id;
  const classTaken = await ClassModel.findOne({
    subject_id: subject_id,
  });

  // add this class to the database of classes taken
  try {
    const newClass = TakenClassesModel(classTaken);
    // LINE BELOW IS WHERE ERROR STARTS
    await newClass.save();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  res.json(classTaken);
});
```

How can I resolve this? Version does not matter to me at all. I simply want to take a whole data from classes and copy it to classes_taken.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a loop around that I don't understand why it works:

Simply do this: define a new variable that is an object with the same exact fields as the original. Then pass this to TakenClassModel.

```
const classTakenS = {
  _id: classTaken._id,
  rating: classTaken.rating,
  title: classTaken.title,
};

const newClass = TakenClassesModel(classTakenS);
await newClass.save();
```

I'm not entirely sure what difference this makes, but it's the only way I can seem to resolve the issue.